# Creating a program to quiz the user on foreign language vocabulary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to write a program that quizzes the user on the translation of foreign words. Basically, the program provides a word and the user is to type in what the English word is for the Spanish one provided. Each time there is a right answer, the program gives an affirmative response; for each incorrect, give the correct answer. The program also needs to keep score and report at how many answers were correct at the end.

```
english_list = ["fire","apple","morning","river","wind"]
spanish_list = ["fuego","manzana","mañana","río","viento"]
english_to_spanish = dict(zip(english_list, spanish_list))
spanish_to_english = dict(zip(spanish_list, english_list))

def translate(word):
    translation = english_to_spanish.get(word)
    if translation:
        return translation

    translation = spanish_to_english.get(word)
    if translation:
        return translation

    raise Exception('Word {0} does not exists'.format(word))

print("Welcome to the English <--> Spanish Quiz")
```

The code is supposed to quiz the user on the entire Spanish dictionary. I am confused on how to set up the code in a quiz format so the user can interact with it effectively. I am supposed to use the foreign words that are a part of pythons dictionary. How would one go about writing a similar code only using the Python dictionary to access these foreign words.

Comment: I suggest `while` loop with first line in the `while` loop being `answer = input('Would you like next word? (Y/N)')` and handle user input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
print('Type each translation, or just hit ENTER to exit.')

for sp, en in spanish_to_english.items():
    response = input(sp + '? ')
    if response == '':
        break  # empty response -> end of quiz
    print(response == en)
    print('')
```

The `response == en` boolean expression will be displayed
as either `True` or `False`.

One could choose to display the correct answer, if desired:

```
    print(response == en)
    if response != en:
        print('The correct answer is:', en)
```

Comment: Is there a way to add a part to the code that returns an error message if you type in the incorrect word?